# How to parse dates from general purpose strings?

Tags: java, json, string, date, datetime

I have input string array of the following form -

```
stringArray1 = {"Vidya", "Balan", "born", "1", "January","1978","is","an","Indian", "actress."}

stringArray2 = {"President", "Franklin", "D.", "Roosevelt","to","proclaim","December", "7,",            "1941,","'a","date","which", "will","live", "in","infamy'"}

stringArray3 = {"The", "Academy", "operated", "until","it","was","destroyed", "by", "Lucius",                               "Cornelius","Sulla","in", "84", "BC"}
```

and I want to be able to apply the following rule to these string arrays :

Any date occurrence should be converted to yyyymmdd format for dates and HH:mm:ss for time  stamps (yyyymmdd HH:mm:ss for both combined).Time zones can be ignored. The following defaults should   be used if any field is absent:
• Year  should be set as 1900.
• Month should  be January
• Date  should  be 1st
• Hour, minute or second should be 00.

Hence the output for the above strings must be:

```
stringOutput1 = { "Vidya", "Balan", "born","19780101","is","an", "Indian","actress." }

stringOutput2 = { "President", "Franklin", "D.","Roosevelt","to","proclaim", "19411207,",   "'a","date","which", "will", "live", "in", "infamy'"}

stringOutput3 = { "The", "Academy", "operated","until", "it", "was", "destroyed", "by","Lucius","Cornelius", "Sulla", "in","-00840101"}
```

I tried using SimpleDateFormatter for this but I think SimpleDateFormatter has no such functionality to do this without specific formats, and I am actually clueless as to how to find a pure java based solution to solve this problem, someone kindly help me out. Also same is the case with time, that is if I have a generic string that consists of a combination of dates and times how do I convert those string.

Comment: What are your rules for determining what IS and ISN'T a date?

Comment: Also, it looks like you combined multiple array elements into one in string one. Specifically, "1", "January", "1978" turned into "19780101". That complicates things a lot, especially since you will have no way of knowing if the first "1" is actually a date without doing some deeper analysis (which again will make things much more difficult.

Comment: yes that is exactly the problem, how should I figure that out, its actually the requirement in a project sadly :(

Comment: This is more an algorithm design question than a programming one.

Comment: I don't know if there is some algorithm that does that its a very strange requirement, I guess it requires more of linguistic analysis and machine learning isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have specific rules for how dates are written (ie. formats) it is impossible to turn arbitrary strings into dates.  The reason for this is ambiguity.  For example:

```
01/02/03
```

In the format `yy/mm/dd` this is February 3, 2001 (let's ignore the possibility of 1901 for the time being).

In the format `mm/dd/yy` this is January 1, 2003.

Etc.